# why console message display multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i make a simple example in jquery .In my example user can added multiple entries using `add` button.
Example **"one" ,"two"** .There is 'X' text in each entry .I am binding click event on 'X' `span` . 
https://jsfiddle.net/kzcozeeg/1/

**Issue** event is bind multiple times why ?
example add two entry "one" and "two" .click "X" on first entry (one) .it show console message two times why ?

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn').click(clickhandler)
    function clickhandler(params) {
        var user= $('.username').val();
        var str = '<div><span>'+user +'</span>  <span class="abc">X</span></div>' 
        $('#wrapper').append(str);
        $('.abc').on('click',function () { 
         console.log($(this).prev('span').text())
         })
    }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: You are nesting event binding, that's why. Use event delegation instead of nesting event binding

Comment: so what is the best way to bind event , so that it fire only one time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Delegate click event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead:

```
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(clickhandler)

  function clickhandler(params) {
    var user = $('.username').val();
    var str = '<div><span>' + user + '</span>  <span class="abc">X</span></div>'
    $('#wrapper').append(str);

  }

  $('#wrapper').on('click', '.abc', function() {
    console.log($(this).prev('span').text())
  })
})
```

This way, you can handle click event on dynamic elements (because click event bubbles).

And your issue was because on each click on `#btn`, you were adding a new click event on each `.abc` elements, without removing any previously bound ones.

Comment: Perhaps say *why* the OP's code did what it did (esp. as the question opens with "Why...").

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, i'll try to improve it but i was looking for dupes, so my bad

Comment: Looking for dupes = good. :-)